# What is wrong in this for loop Liquid Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1HcS.png)

{%- for product in collection.products limit:4 -%}
{%- if collection.handle contains 'collection-handle' -%}

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a '|'.

{%- for product in collection.products | limit:4 -%}

Rather than the original:

{%- for product in collection.products limit:4 -%}